Generate scaladocs with scaladoc 3
I feel like I'm missing something basic. What is it?

I have a square.scala file:
> cat square.scala
/** This is the square function */
def square(d: Double): Double = d * d


The scaladoc CLI does not accept raw *.scala files:
> scaladoc --version
Scaladoc version 3.6.2 -- Copyright 2002-2024, LAMP/EPFL

> scaladoc square.scala
scaladoc supports only .tasty and .jar files,
following files will be ignored: square.scala


I can compile it into a JAR file:
> scalac --version
Scala compiler version 3.6.2 -- Copyright 2002-2024, LAMP/EPFL

> scalac square.scala -d square.jar

> jar tf square.jar
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
square$package$.class
square$package.class
square$package.tasty


And then try to generate the scaladocs:
> mkdir output

> scaladoc square.jar -d output

> ls output
favicon.ico  fonts  hljs  images  scaladoc.version  scripts  styles  webfonts

Notice, I get a folder with webpage-like stuff... but nothing about my square function. I expected some HTML listing my square function and my comment.


What do I not understand?

As far as I can tell, scaladoc wants the name of your .scala file, not the corresponding .jar...

@jasonharper... if I do scaladoc square.scala, it responds, "scaladoc supports only .tasty and .jar files"

@jasonharper... updated the post to mention scaladoc square.scala. Thank you!
